# Pass methods in interface

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IModuleTile
{
    void AddEvent(/*Type here*/ methodToAdd);
    void RemoveEvent(/*Type here*/ methodToRemove);
}
```

And I want to do this:

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl, IModuleTile
{
    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void AddEvent(/*Type here*/ eventToAdd)
    {
        ShowModule.Click += methodToAdd;
    }

    public void RemoveEvent(/*Type here*/ methodToRemove);
    {
        ShowModule.Click += methodToRemove;
    }
}
```

What do I have to set as the interface type to pass methods?

Comment: [Pass a Delegate of some sort..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)

Comment: You know you can actually declare events on interfaces, right?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do here is just put an event directly into the interface, rather than explicitly adding add/remove methods.

```
public interface IModuleTile
{ 
    //change `EventHandler` to match whatever the event handler type 
    //is for the event that you're "wrapping", if needed
    event EventHandler MyClick;
}
```

Then the implementation can be something like:

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl, IModuleTile
{
    //You'll need to change `EventHandler` here too, if you changed it above
    public event EventHandler MyClick
    {
        add
        {
            ShowModule.Click += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            ShowModule.Click -= value;
        }
    }
}
```